# jQuery mouseover function only works for one div

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that on hover will show some icons, I am very new to jQuery and can't for the life of me work out why it only works on one div.

I have multiple divs this function needs to work with.

My jQuery:

```
$("#hovercam").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#textfieldlonger').css('margin-top', '200px');
    $('#hovericons').css('display', '');
 });
$("#hovercam").mouseleave(function() {
  $('#textfieldlonger').css('margin-top', '180px');
  $('#hovericons').css('display', 'none');
});
```

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    .....
});
```

But this did not do the trick.

All my Div's are

```
<div id="hovercam">
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it only works on one div."? It should, because the id of an element must be unique. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your HTML, so that all the div s will have unique id and same class name.

```
<div id="hoverCam1" class="hovercam">
</div>
```

And the your jQuery will be

```
$("#someparentelement").find("div.hovercam").hover(function(){
}, function() {
});
```

Read [HTML ID attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id) and
[.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)